# Ckeditor toolbar not entirely showing up

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have just moved my site from local machine to production, the wysiwyg editor based on ckeditor no longer show the complete toolbar. I have a minimal list of element.
Can someone help, am trying everything, edit profile, check if all files are uploaded, i don't see any problem !

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer:

Go to "Home › Administer › Site configuration › CKEditor".

Then select an individual profile in the upper section (not the Global settings).

You'll be on the "Edit CKEditor profile" page, where there is an "Editor appearance" section. The 6th item down (just below the color picker) is the ***toolbar selector***.

There are 5 options, if none of the selections meet your needs, you can easily create a custom toolbar with exactly the buttons that you want to have available.

The module author included a note below the toolbar selector, you can open the "ckeditor.config.js" located in "sites/all/modules/ckeditor" and create your custom toolbar there. It will appear in the selector after you create it.

I've included all of the buttons available for the normal CKEditor, but the module author has added some that are specific to Drupal. You can take a look at them in the config.js file.

Here are the standard plugin buttons, you can pick and choose which ones you want:

```
[ 'Source','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ]
[ 'Link','Unlink' ]
[ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','-','SpellChecker' ]
[ 'Source','About','InsertSnippet','BGColor','SimpleLink', 'Select', 'SelectToText', 'SelectorUpdateSelector','SimpleLink' ]
[ 'About','BGColor' ]
[ 'Format','Font','FontSize' ]
[ 'TextColor' ]
[ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ]
[ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock' ]
```

Be Well,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

Install the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module; that will fix your problem.

Comment: You saved me after an hour. Of course, who installs this module should update (via admin/config/development/jquery_update) the Jquery to use version 1.8. (as of today). Thanks!